# How can I avoid using forEach when iterating over mongodb documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm attempting to run a MongoDB migration:

```js
db.users.find().forEach(user => {
  if (user.group) {
    const groupId = user.group;
    const dateAddedToGroup = user.dateAddedToGroup || null;

    db.users.update(
      { _id: user._id },
      {
        $addToSet: {
          groups: { groupId, dateAddedToGroup },
        },
      }
    );
  }
});
```

However I want to avoid using `forEach` due to the performance loss. How can I do so?

If I attempt this then I'll be told that `users is not iterable`:

```js
const users = db.users.find();

for (const user of users) {
  if (user.group) {
    const groupId = user.group;
    const dateAddedToGroup = user.dateAddedToGroup || null;

    db.users.update(
      { _id: user._id },
      {
        $addToSet: {
          groups: { groupId, dateAddedToGroup },
        },
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What performance loss?

Comment: Looping through thousands of objects rather than performing the update in place

Comment: Maybe I mis-read this, but both of your code fragments appear to be doing largely the same thing which is to call `db.users.update()` in a loop that iterates N times. Neither would be significantly more performant than the other. That said, if your MongoDB SDK supports [db.collection.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) then that might be a good option.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Is there a simple way to write this update with that? Is this different to updateMany?

Comment: I don't use MongoDB so I don't know if using the `$addToSet` operation is viable in `updateMany` and `bulkWrite` (I would presume it is OK) so I'd give it a try with a couple of updates. Then work out what's a reasonable number of updates to send in a single API call, then construct he necessary payload for the API.

Comment: You may want to add a sample document to the post and tell what field  you are trying to update.